# bisectLeft function does not work if the second parameter is numerical

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In a small routine that I am implementing I use the bisectLeft function of d3.js.
I am using the latest version (v5.9.2).
If I do this, everything is fine:

```
var dataArray = [10, 20, 50, 40, 30, 600];
d3.bisectLeft(dataArray, 30); //2
```

But if I do this, no:

```
var dataArray = [[10,1],[20,2],[50,5],[40,4],[30,3],[600,60]];
d3.bisectLeft(dataArray, 30); //0 Bad!
```

This, however, works well:

```
var dataArray = [[10,1],[20,2],[50,5],[40,4],[30,3],[600,60]];
d3.bisectLeft(dataArray, '30'); //2 Good!
```

Is this so by design? I have reviewed the source code and documentation and I don't understand why it happens.
Once known the problem is very easy to fix in my code, but I still have the doubt and I don't know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you have an array of arrays. In that case, you have to use [`d3.bisector`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#bisector) with the adequate accessor function, so D3 can know what's the value to compare. According tho the docs, this method...

> Returns a new bisector using the specified accessor or comparator function. This method can be used to bisect arrays of objects instead of being limited to **simple arrays of primitives**. (emphasis mine)

In your case, this will be:

```
const bisector = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d[0]; }).left;
```

As you can see, this will effectively turn the array of arrays into a single array of numbers by picking the first number in each inner array, just like the first snippet in your question.

Also, pay attention to the fact that the array needs to be sorted (or else people will never understand why `2` is *"good"* in your question!).

This is the demo:

```js
var dataArray = [
  [10, 1],
  [20, 2],
  [50, 5],
  [40, 4],
  [30, 3],
  [600, 60]
];
dataArray = dataArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[0] - b[0];
});
const bisector = d3.bisector(function(d) {
  return d[0];
}).left;
const result = bisector(dataArray, 30);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Beat me to it, nice answer. Need a warning that you're typing an answer to save time.

Comment: @AndrewReid The mystery remains: why and how did the string work for the bisector? You may want to investigate that and post it as an answer.

Comment: This fixes it. Thank you!